# How do I center the column header in my datagrid XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am trying to make my datagrid look more like a listview.
I would like to center the text "name"
And then remove that vertical black bar that is to the right of the items.
[image]

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="DGCHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>

        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#303030" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="DGHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
        <Setter Property="ColumnHeaderStyle" Value="{DynamicResource DGCHeaderStyle}"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Foreground="Black" HeadersVisibility="Column" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Black" RowBackground="Transparent" x:Name="dgItems" Margin="2,0,10,10" Style="{DynamicResource DGHeaderStyle}"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard coding the value like you have done will work, but it defeats one of the major features of WPF which is scalability of controls and views.

Rather than a hard-coded '525' value, setting the `ColumnWidth` property on the `DataGrid` itself would give you better design flexibility:

```
<DataGrid ColumnWidth="*"/>
```

That way, no matter how many columns you have, or how wide/narrow your window or `DataGrid` get, the column(s) will always take up all of the available space in the `DataGrid`.

In WPF terms the `*` means "Use all the remaining space" in the container.

Comment: ColumnWidth is easily broken in various situations. In fact, DataGrid is so extremely broken, I would highly suggest for everyone to stay away from it. If you need a control with similar functionality, you can easily homebrew your own in the same amount of time that it would take to solve just one DataGrid problem. DataGrid is quite easily the most broken control in the WPF framework.

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
<Setter Property="Width" Value="525"/>
```

To

```
<Style x:Key="DGCHeaderStyle"  TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
```

Fixed it